# MSIL question about field reference

Tags: compiler-construction, cil

I have a class which has a private variable of type generic Stack.
Inside the class I've declared a Foo method.
After examining the IL I've noticed that the target of the method Push is actually the method call set_Property2 rather then the field of the class.
How does the compiler actually make the connection between the two?

```
public class A
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class ShortDemo
{
    private Stack<A> _stack = new Stack<A>();

    private void Foo()
    {
        _stack.Push(new A()
        {
            Property1 = 1,
            Property2 = 2
        });
    }
}
```

And the IL:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void Foo() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication1.A g__initLocal0)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldfld class [System]System.Collections.Generic.Stack1 ConsoleApplication1.ShortDemo::_stack
    L_0007: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.A::.ctor()
    L_000c: stloc.0 
    L_000d: ldloc.0 
    L_000e: ldc.i4.1 
    L_000f: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.A::set_Property1(int32)
    L_0014: nop 
    L_0015: ldloc.0 
    L_0016: ldc.i4.2 
    L_0017: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.A::set_Property2(int32)
    L_001c: nop 
    L_001d: ldloc.0 
    L_001e: callvirt instance void [System]System.Collections.Generic.Stack1::Push(!0)
    L_0023: nop 
    L_0024: ret 
}
```

Comment: Your field is loaded at L_0024, then the method's arguments are placed on the stack, and then `Push` is called at L_0052.  What's the question?

Comment: There's too much going on here to make it easy to analyze. Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates this, with as short a method as you can.

Comment: I've noticed that it occurs only when I use object initializers. When I create new instance of A and then push it to the stack the ldfld line is omitted from L_0002 and inserted at L_001a which makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem. Here are the options:

```
A a = new A() { ... };
_stack.Push(args)
```

translates to:

- Create object and store reference in local 0
- Load _stack field
- Load local 0
- Call Push

Now your "embedded" object initializer version:

```
_stack.Push(new A() { ... });
```

translates to:

- Load _stack field
- Create object and store in local 0
- Load local 0
- Call Push

In both cases, the stack ends up with the field and the argument. It's just that in the "embedded" object initializer version, there's more stuff going on between loading the field and calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

According to reflector
L_0001: "this" reference is at the top.
L_0002: the field reference is at the top after poping the value from the stack.
L_0007: new ConsoleApplication1.A object is at the top.
L_000c: an assign expression is at the top after poping the value from the stack.

(So now we have two expressions assign at the top and field reference).

L_000d: varaible reference at the top.
L_000e: literal int value at the top.
L_000f: set_Property1 method call at the top after poping the literal value to use as
an argument and the variable reference as a target.
(now we have 3 expressions method call to set_Property1, assign expression and then the field
reference).

L_0017: same as L_000f ending in method call addition to the stack 
(set_Property2, set_Property1, assign, field reference).
L_001d: varaible reference
(variable reference, set_Property2, set_Property1...)

L_001e: the push method expects a target and one argument. If i assume that this line works the same as line L_000f the target that is at the top of the stack is set_Property2.

I don't understand why you wrote that the stack ends up with the field and the argument.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It would have been better as a question edit.